# Laravel login column handling

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table column named "Status" Here is the Schema:

```
Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('Status')->default('0');
        });
```

It's a boolean that's added to my table "users." Its function is to find out if a user is logged in on the admin dashboard. Here is my Auth controller@login :

```
 public function login(Request $request)
    {
         $validateData = $request->validate([
         'email' => 'required',
         'password' => 'required',
         
     ]);



    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Email or Password Invalid'], 401);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

Basic stuff, but what I wanted to do is if the user accesses this controller through loggin in that the value of the boolean in `status` column in the user's table turns to `1` for true instead of `0` meaning false. I'm new to laravel so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try it like this, by providing the status you want as well in the credentials array :

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
         $validateData = $request->validate([
         'email' => 'required',
         'password' => 'required',
         
     ]);



    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);
    $credentials['Status'] = 1;
    if(!Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Email or Password Invalid'], 401);
    }

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to update user status after logging in

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $validateData = $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',  
    ]);

    $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

    if (! $token = auth()->attempt($credentials)) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'Email or Password Invalid'], 401);
    }

    // update user status if logged in
    auth()->user()->update([
        'status' => true,
    ]);

    return $this->respondWithToken($token);
}
```

Comment: Hello, it doesn't work. I'm using the query builder method. I tried 'Status' => true and 'Status' => '1' and it doesn't update.